# How to publish locally, 3rd party libraries with SBT?

Tags: maven, sbt, publish

I would like to publish locally some third-party libraries. How can you do that in sbt. It would be the equivalent of the following maven approach: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Best,

-M-